# s3fs unmount: directory is not empty

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs, umount

I'm using [`s3fs`](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon) and [`osxfuse`](https://osxfuse.github.io/) to mount an S3 directory on my Mac:

```
s3fs my-bucket-name $PWD/s3
```

When it's time to unmount it, I do this:

```
% s3fs umount $PWD/s3
s3fs: MOUNTPOINT directory /Users/kwilliams/blah/s3 is not empty.
if you are sure this is safe, can use the 'nonempty' mount option.
```

I am **not** sure this is safe - I didn't knowingly create any new files in the `s3` directory, and if any new ones were created, I need to know about it so I can clean them up or figure out what happened.

I also don't want it to perform any actions (creation, deletion) on the underlying S3 bucket when trying to unmount.  I'm not sure what the `nonempty` option will do.

The directory certainly appears nonempty when I do `ls`, because it shows me the contents of the bucket.

Finally - the message says I can `use the 'nonempty' mount option` - is it saying I should have used that option at mount time, or I can use it when unmounting?  `s3fs --help` doesn't indicate that `s3fs umount` can take any options.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Okay, I feel silly - I figured out the answer right after posting.  I'm not supposed to do `s3fs umount $PWD/s3`, just `umount $PWD/s3`.

The former is presumably trying to mount another bucket called `umount` at the same path where the previous one is mounted.

Comment: Not silly - 37 other people including me seemed to have the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

In a normal case, you can simply unmount the directory using umount from the root

```
$ umount /mountpoint
```

For unprivileged user

```
fusermount -u /mountpoint
```

else use this to umount directly if shows Device or resource busy / directory is not empty / Permission denied

```
umount -l /mounthpath
```

and do rm -rf /path if not needed anymore.
FYI : needed more details about s3fs https://www.mankier.com/1/s3fs#

Answer (score 1):

You can also use fusermount:

```
fusermount -u $PWD/s3
```

You may need to [install](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fusermount.1.html) fusermount first

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Just `umount mount-point` is enough.